# Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found. Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to build a web vulnerability scanner and when building I'm constantly experiencing the following problem:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.  Software being installed: Subgraph Vega
>   1.0.0.201706211002 (com.subgraph.vega.application.product 1.0.0.201706211002)  Missing requirement: jsoup 1.7.3.SNAPSHOT (org.jsoup 1.7.3.SNAPSHOT) requires 'package org.jsoup 1.7.0' but it
>   could not be found  Cannot satisfy dependency:  Cannot satisfy
>   dependency:

Even though I have added the jsoup snapshot to the build path it still is showing me the same error message. I think it's a bug and if someone has a workarount or a solution it would be much appreciated!

I have tried different Eclipse versions as well switched from 32 bit to 64 bit and I keep getting the same error message every time!

[image: ERROR]
![ERROR][1]

Comment: Are you really _building_? The error you are experiencing is typical during _installing_ Eclipse plugins.

Comment: @AndréStannek Hi! I am exporting the project to an .exe runnable file and I keep getting this error. So i assume the right term is during the build?

Comment: Sounds a little strange to me but then again I'm not familiar with Subgraph Vega. What way are you building? How are you adding jsoup to the build path?

Comment: @AndréStannek properties -> libraries -> add external jars -> select the jsoup jar -> Order and Export -> check the jsoup jar and hit apply